# How to match a file line by line with a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file in python that has one word on each line and I need to return a list of every word that matches with a passed in regular expression with a function load_words.  For example:load_words("words",r"^[A-Z].{2}$") should return ['A-1', 'AAA', 'AAE'] and others which makes sense because these 3 all fit the expression where you start with a capital letter then have 2 of anything.  Here is my current function:

```
def load_words(filename,regexp):
    f=open(filename)
    t=[]
    x=None
    for line in f:
        x=(re.match(regexp,line))
        if x!=None:
            t.append(x)
    return t
```

I try to read the file line by line and if the line matches with the expression, I add it to the list.  Im not quite sure what function in re I need to match regular expressions with srings so I might be using the wrong one in all likeliness because my output is looks like addresses instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are collecting the [Match objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) in a list, but need to get the matches from the [group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group). Replace:

```
t.append(x)
```

with:

```
t.append(x.group(0))
```

---

Note that you don't need to check the `x` not to be `None` and can simply check for it to be "truthy":

```
x = re.match(regexp, line)
if x:
    t.append(x.group(0))
```

Comment: what does x.group(0) do? why 0 in particular

Comment: @AnatoliySokolov I've added links to the documentation. 0 would refer to the entire match. Hope it helps.

Comment: I looked at it and Im trying to test some outputs to understand it better.  I tried doing:  m = re.match(r"^[A-Z].{2}$,"Hih Hid idos")  but thats giving me a syntax error, any idea why? Im very new to this

Comment: @AnatoliySokolov sure, you have not closed the quotes (missing `"` after the regular expression).

Answer (score 0):

def load_words(filename,regexp):

```
f=open(filename)

data = f.read()

t = re.findall(regexp,data,re.MULTILINE)

return t
```

Comment: This is incorrect without the `MULTILINE` flag. Try OP's example `r"^[A-Z].{2}$"`. Nothing will be matched unless the file has only one line.